# spread nav bar across whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am doing some responsive CSS and I want to have something like this:

```
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li>Asd</li>
 <li>sdf</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<table>
 (Some wide table goes here)
</table>
```

I defined the nav as a bar on top of the page(=horizontal bar).
With small screens (when the table is too big) , the horizontal scrolling bar appears.

My problem is, that when I scroll horizontaly, the nav bar goes to left and leaves a blank space on right side. I just want it to be visible, to keep the impression of bar. Are there any ideas how to do it?

I know, one of them would be position:fixed, so the nav keeps fixed, but that would also mean the nav will be fixed even with verticall scroll, which I don't want.

I just want it to be simply as wide as the whole page (not just as wide as screen), while also being possible to scroll vertically. (It quite doesn't matter to me if the nav content scroll too when horizontal scroll occurs or if the nav content just gets scrolled and there is just nav background (and nav border and so on))

EDIT: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/201302202145541024x600s.png/

Comment: If the table an actual table of values, or is it being used for layout purposes? You can always wrap it in a DIV with overflow-x:scroll.

Answer (score 0):

with CSS, `position:absolute; left:0;` (stops it from moving away from the left side of the web-screen when page scrolls.)

Comment: Sorry, but you probably misunderstood me. I don't mind the nav to move, my problem is that it doesn't fit all free space (it is just one screen wide and I need it to be over whole page (eg. two, three, thousand screens, depending on the width of other content))

Comment: Ohhhh! My bad, I would look into javascript for that then.

Comment: And what JS are you suggesting? I'm trying to do it whole day, but there are still some errors when resizing the page
I've actually managed to do script that adds `paddingRight` to nav, so it fills whole `document.body.scrollWidth`, but I'm having problems when resizing the page, because the padding is too big (this leads to page actually being bigger than necessary and displaying unneeded horizontal scrollbar)

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with Javascript. I re-tagged your question to have "Javascript" in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you fully, but I think the solution to your problem would be to use CSS to set an `overflow: hidden` parameter.

You can do this with a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your internal/external CSS, like so:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table {
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Otherwise, you could add it directly using inline CSS with a style attribute, which doesn't take up as much space but only applies to that specific table (and not all tables on a page). For example:

```html
<body>
  <table style="overflow:hidden">
   (Some wide table goes here)
  </table>
</body>
```